# PHP check if referer domain is a search engine

Tags: php, dns, search-engine, host

I'm looking for a way to identify referers domains, in order to categorize Search Engines and other domain types.

So far i have been able to set an array with a list of domains that can be considered Search Engines and use `in_array()` to compare `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable with every array's element.

```
$searchDomains = array('www.google.com','google.com','www.bing.com','bing.com','www.yahoo.com','yahoo.com','www.ask.com','www.duckduckgo.com','www.ecosia.org');

$parse = parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); //let's say https://www.google.com/

foreach($searchDomains as $dom){
  if($parse['host'] == $dom){
    // Hit! Is a search engine
  } else {
    // Another type of website
  }
}
```

My problem comes when the referer domain doesn't match any of the array's elements, so it takes domains like `google.com.co` as non Search Engine, since isn't in the array list. Of course i can add every known google domain to this array, but this will only last until they decide to register a new domain in a new country.

I have come with the idea that i can search for `google` substring inside whatever contains `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`, and if it matchs, take it as true, but domains like `googlewhatever.com` (asuming it exists) or `https://asdf.com/we-like-google/` will match wrongly as true.

In this particular case, i'm using search engines domains, but in the future i may be using universities domains, or ecommerce domains or whatever category.

Any idea?

Comment: 1) Don't do substring search but proper hostname matching but 2) make sure to remember there is no guarantee that the HTTP `referer` field is set and if set, it is arbitrary, so any client can use any string; 3) some for `user-agent` that could also be used to identify search engines, with the same caveats as 2)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek that’s two completely different scenarios though. The referrer would tell you your site visitor came from a search engine result page, whereas the user agent only would indicate a search engine for the requests made by their bots.

Comment: As you say, may be some users can modify the referer, but in general that will represent a tiny part of the total referers, the idea is intended to be shown as a pie chart in a general referers view, nothing else

Answer (score 1):

As you are already parsing the url, what I would do in this case, is to do a regex check on the hostname. fx:

```
function is_search_engine_referer() {
    $search_engine_terms = [ 'google', 'bing', 'yahoo', 'ask', 'duckduckgo', 'ecosia' ];

    $referer_url = filter_input( INPUT_SERVER, 'HTTP_REFERER', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING ); // Let's say https://www.google.com/
    $referer_host = parse_url( $referer_url, PHP_URL_HOST ); // www.google.com

    foreach ( $search_engine_terms as $term ) {
        // Check if referer matches search term with a dot after and possibly a dot before.
        // This will allow any subdomains as well
        if ( preg_match( '/\.?' . preg_quote( $term, '/' ) . '\./i', $referer_host ) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

However this is not a failsafe function, as it would match google.example.com etc.

Actually I don't think there is a perfect solution for this, that don't require you to constantly and manually keep track of which domains are being used by various search engines around the world.

Your post doesn't provide much info about usage, but another solution could be to save a row in your database with the referer for each new visitor, and then process the data at a later time, making it easier to check the individual referers, group domains etc.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for you answer... as you said, this is not a failsafe, but it just work for reference only. May be some users can modify the referer, but in general that will represent a tiny part of the total referers, this info is intended to be shown as a pie chart and be visualized